# I have a function that I want to use to separate data into lists using this boolean function

Tags: javascript, date, boolean, tablerow

```
function date_is_in_the_future(dateAdd){
    // turn '2018-01-01' from a string to an object
    input_date_object = new Date(dateAdd);
    // Get todays date as an object
    today_date = new Date();
    // if the inpute_date_object is bigger than today_date, it will return false
    boolean_result = input_date_object > today_date;
    // return result 
    return boolean_result;
}
```

What do I have to do to this function in order to use it in my JavaScript?

Comment: Just use it! What is your question?

Comment: Note that '2018-01-01' will likely be parsed as UTC, so will be a different local date for hosts in time zones west of Greenwich..

Answer (score 0):

Just call it;

```js
console.log(date_is_in_the_future('2019-01-01'));
console.log(date_is_in_the_future('2017-01-01'));
function date_is_in_the_future(dateAdd){
   //turn '2018-01-01' from a string to an object
   input_date_object = new Date(dateAdd)
   //Get todays date as an object
   today_date = new Date()
   //if the inpute_date_object is bigger than today_date, it will return false
   boolean_result = input_date_object > today_date
   //return result 
   return boolean_result
}
```

Comment: '2019-01-01' will be parsed as UTC, so for some `new Date('2018-01-01') < new Date(2018,0,1)` will return false and for others return true.